# Inconsistent indentation in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I am an Emacs (and Stack Exchange) newbie, but I think I did my reading. I don't know why Emacs shows an inconsistent indentation in documents longer than one screen. My relevant settings are:

```
(setq org-hide-leading-stars nil)
(setq org-startup-folded 0)
(setq org-startup-indented t)
(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
```

I use vanilla Emacs with a minimal (~100 lines) config. It seems that the indentation looks correct on the page which is visible when I load org-mode, but incorrect on other pages. When I use PgDn or PgUp to get to those pages, the incorrect indentation is revealed. If I change to text-mode and back to org-mode, the indentation will be okay on the screen I currently see.

I would like to have indentation like in the top paragraph, not that strange first-line indentation in the bottom paragraph. Is it possible to fix this? Thanks for any help!

SOLUTION: I had this problem with Emacs 26, but an upgrade to Emacs 28 solved everything.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on `visual-line-mode`.

According to `info` entry

***Org Indent mode also sets `wrap-prefix` correctly for indenting and wrapping long lines of headlines or text.  This minor mode also handles `Visual Line mode` and directly applied settings through `word-wrap`.***

---

The `Org Ind` in your `mode-line` is the give away ...  Try turning `org-indent-mode` OFF.

`org-indent-mode` is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in
`org-indent.el`.

```lisp
(org-indent-mode &optional ARG)
```

When active, indent text according to outline structure.

Internally this works by adding `line-prefix` and `wrap-prefix`
properties, after each buffer modification, on the modified zone.

The process is synchronous.  Though, initial indentation of buffer, which can take a few seconds on large buffers, is done during idle time.

This is a minor mode.  If called interactively, toggle the `Org-Indent mode` mode.  If the prefix argument is positive, enable the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable the mode.

If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if `ARG` is `toggle`.  Enable the mode if `ARG` is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.  Disable the mode if `ARG` is a negative number.

To check whether the minor mode is enabled in the current buffer, evaluate `org-indent-mode`.

The mode`s hook is called both when the mode is enabled and when it is disabled.

---

From

```lisp
(info "(org) Org Indent Mode")
```

or

[16.4.1 Org Indent Mode | Emacs Docs](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/org/Org-Indent-Mode)

### 17.4.1 Org Indent Mode

To display the buffer in the indented view, activate Org Indent minor mode, using ``M`-x org-indent-mode`.  Text lines that are not headlines are prefixed with virtual spaces to vertically align with the headline text(1).

(1) Org Indent mode also sets `wrap-prefix` correctly for indenting and wrapping long lines of headlines or text.  This minor mode also handles Visual Line mode and directly applied settings through `word-wrap`.

To make more horizontal space, the headlines are shifted by two characters.  Configure `org-indent-indentation-per-level` variable for a different number.

By default, Org Indent mode turns off `org-adapt-indentation` and does hide leading stars by locally setting `org-hide-leading-stars` to `t`: only one star on each headline is visible, the rest are masked with the same font color as the background.  If you want to customize this default behavior, see `org-indent-mode-turns-on-hiding-stars` and `org-indent-mode-turns-off-org-adapt-indentation`.

To globally turn on Org Indent mode for all files, customize the variable `org-startup-indented`.  To control it for individual files, use `STARTUP` keyword as follows:

```
 #+`STARTUP`: indent
 #+`STARTUP`: noindent
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I wasn't clear. I like the indentation. I would like the contents of lower-level headings to be more indented on display (but not in the file, hence org-indent-mode and not org-adapt-indentation). And it works. If I type, Org indents everything nicely as seen on the top paragraph. The bottom paragraph, however, has a first-line-indent, but its second line is not indented. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Please update your question.  I have updated the answer.  See the first few paragraphs of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74158/31220

Comment: I apologize for the trouble, but I have read these things before and I think I understand them. As you can see from the question, visual-line-mode is currently enabled in my Emacs config. But why is the paragraph after the first heading correctly indented, and the second one not? If you are wondering: the file itself does not contain any hard indentation, and the error appears in all files.

Comment: The solution was quite simple. I am using Ubuntu GNU/Linux, and it only had Emacs 26.3. After installing 28.2 from Snap, the Org indentation behavior suddenly became flawless. So it seems I stepped on a long-repaired bug. Thanks!